# Declaration of 2 Dimensional Array in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing

It is possible in processing to initialize and declare a one dimensional array in two steps, or in one.

```
int []a;

a= new int[100];
```

which is equivalent to :

```
int [] a=new int [100];
```

I would like to know if there is a similar method as above to do the same for 2 dimensional array.

```
int [][] array= new int[100][200];
```

Comment: what language are you writing in?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen PROCESSING

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just try splitting the statement to int [][] array;
array = new int[100][200];

Comment: i need it. in the useage of the array inside a class. and to retrive it using an object. somewhat like the application of arraylist

Comment: Please post more of your code to help us understand...

Comment: my program is too big to post them. i will try to explain the use i am expecting.

actually i have two classes Class A and Class B.
now i need to pass strigs of different sizes to Class B and split them by the code split. each string is passed b different objects (say object array). now in class B i need to split the string and store each corresponding numeric into int. (note: the string contains numbers followed by ',' ie, my String is of the for 21,32,45,85 etc). Now if i am able to do it as per i have asked, the class function could do the same function of the arraylist in my program.

Answer (score 1):

```
// this??

int[][] a;

a = new int [100][200];

println("a.\'x\' length: " + a.length);
println("a.\'y\' length: " + a[0].length);

//or maybe... this?

int[][] b;

b = new int [100][];


for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
  b[i] = new int[200];
}

println("b.\'x\' length: " + b.length);
println("b.\'y\' length: " + b[0].length);
```

Sure you know you can have a two dimensions arraylist also