# Two-dimensional arrays Processing

Tags: arrays, for-loop, foreach, processing, multidimensional-array

If I'm creating a 2-d boolean array in Processing, I would use the code:

```
boolean[][] elemts = new boolean[500][500];
```

After I create this array, are all the values false, true, or null by default? If it isn't false, how do I use a for loop or for-each loop to set all the values to false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaration of 2 Dimensional Array in Processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539780/declaration-of-2-dimensional-array-in-processing)

Comment: I already know how to create it, I just wanted to know how to cycle through it with a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < elemts.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < elemts[0].length; j++)
  {
    elemts[i][j] = false;
  }
}
```

Make sure to put this in a function, like void setup(). This changes every element to false.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code yo set all values to false.

```
for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<500; j++){
    elements[i][j] = false;
  }
}
```

Anyway they are all false for default, you can test this by:

```
    boolean[] test = new boolean[4];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      println(test[i]);
    }
```

If you test this you'll see that you get all false values, because they are false for default.
Regards
Jose